# Differentiating between Windows Services with the same name?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm working on an application that does some interaction with Windows Services.  I'm using the [ServiceController class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) to handle the interaction, but I'm wondering what will happen if I encounter two services with the same name.

In the sample code provided in the documentation, they address the services by name, like so:

```
foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
  if (scTemp.ServiceName == "Simple Service"){  /* Do Work */ }
```

I don't see any stipulations requiring `ServiceName` to be unique.  If two services are named the same, yet the user only wishes to interact with one of them, how do I handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Service names must be unique, according to the [`CreateService` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ERROR_DUPLICATE_SERVICE_NAME
>
> The display name already exists in the service control manager database either as a service name or as another display name.

Answer (score 2):

Services are registered by their ServiceName in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services registry key.  Have a look at it with Regedit.exe and compare what you see when you iterate ServiceController.GetServices().

So there can never be a duplicate, trying to get the duplicate registered will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Service names do need to be unique. InstallUtil will throw an exception if you try to install a service with an existing name.